# What is your solution to the "Escape from Zurg" puzzle in C#?

Tags: c#, puzzle

found this puzzle [HERE](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/Zurg_JFP04.pdf)... I made a brute force solution and I would like to know how you woul solve it...

Buzz, Woody, Rex, and Hamm have to escape from Zurg(a) They merely have to cross
one last bridge before they are free. However, the bridge is fragile and can hold at most
two of them at the same time. Moreover, to cross the bridge a flashlight is needed to
avoid traps and broken parts. The problem is that our friends have only one flashlight
with one battery that lasts for only 60 minutes (this is not a typo: sixty). The toys need
different times to cross the bridge (in either direction):

```
 TOY     TIME
Buzz   5 minutes
Woody 10 minutes
Rex   20 minutes
Hamm  25 minutes
```

Since there can be only two toys on the bridge at the same time, they cannot cross the
bridge all at once. Since they need the flashlight to cross the bridge, whenever two have
crossed the bridge, somebody has to go back and bring the flashlight to those toys on
the other side that still have to cross the bridge.
The problem now is: In which order can the four toys cross the bridge in time (that
is, in 60 minutes) to be saved from Zurg?

```
//(a) These are characters from the animation movie “Toy Story 2”.
```

here is my solution:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    List<toy> toys = new List<toy>(){
        new toy { name = "buzz", time = 5 } ,
        new toy { name = "woody", time = 10 } ,
        new toy { name = "rex", time = 20 } ,
        new toy { name = "ham", time = 25 } ,
        };
    var posibles = Combinaciones(toys, 4).ToList(); //all permutations
    List<Tuple<string, int>> solutions = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();

    foreach (var pointA in posibles)
    {
        string order = "";
        int flashlight = 60;
        List<toy> pointB = new List<toy>();
        do
        {
            var fastestInA = pointA.Take(2).ToList();
            flashlight -= fastestInA.Max(t => t.time);
            order += "go " + String.Join(",", fastestInA.Select(t => t.name)) + "\n";
            fastestInA.ForEach(t => pointA.Remove(t));
            pointB.AddRange(fastestInA);
            if (pointB.Count < 4)
            {
                var fastestInB = pointB.Take(1).ToList();
                flashlight -= fastestInB.Max(t => t.time);
                order += "return " + String.Join(",", fastestInB.Select(t => t.name).ToArray()) + "\n";
                fastestInB.ForEach(t => pointB.Remove(t));
                pointA.AddRange(fastestInB);
            }
        } while (pointB.Count != 4);

        solutions.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(order, flashlight));
    }

    var optimal = solutions.Where(s => s.Item2 == solutions.Max(t => t.Item2)).ToList();
    optimal.ForEach(s => Console.Write("Order:\n" + s.Item1 + "TimeLeft:" + s.Item2 + "\n\n"));
}

public class toy
{
    public int time { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

// this is to do permutations
public static List<List<toy>> Combinaciones(List<toy> list, int take)
{
    List<List<toy>> combs = new List<List<toy>>();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        var newlist = list.Where(i => !i.Equals(item)).ToList();
        var returnlist = take <= 1 ? new List<List<toy>> { new List<toy>() } : Combinaciones(newlist, take - 1);
        foreach (var l in returnlist)
        {
            l.Add(item);
        }
        combs.AddRange(returnlist);
    }

    return combs.ToList();
}
}
```

Comment: Although you're asking about the brute-force method, the trigger-point to actually solve the puzzle is to realise that you can't afford to waste the 20 minute and the 25 minute times on separate crossings

Comment: actually I found this problem looking for some newbie material for AI so the actual challenge is to have the computer realize that w/o telling explicitly.

Comment: The solution is simple, but I'm not sure how to create an algorithm for how to solve this.

Comment: Are you looking for code that can handle variations on the problem (different lengths of time, different numbers of toys) or just this specific structure (4 toys that can in the best cases match the time limit)?

Comment: I had a very similar question on an interview once, though we just had to solve it logically... not write a program.  My solution:  The 5 minute guy carries the 25 minute guy across the bridge.  The time averages out for carrying the extra weight, so it's 15 minutes for that trip and 55 for the total at the end.  I still say I was right.  :P

Comment: This is also a way to solve the exercies from the university.

Comment: @buckbova - I've solved this (not in C#) and can handle @svick's example with times (1,5,5,5) or any other I've tested... but I think calling it an *algorithm* might be a bit of a stretch! ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recursive solution using LINQ:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Zurg
{
  class Program
  {
    static readonly Toy[] toys = new Toy[]{
        new Toy("Buzz", 5),
        new Toy("Woody", 10),
        new Toy("Rex", 20),
        new Toy("Ham", 25),
        };
    static readonly int totalTorch = 60;

    static void Main()
    {
      Console.WriteLine(Go(new State(toys, new Toy[0], totalTorch, "")).Message);
    }

    static State Go(State original)
    {
      var final = (from first in original.Start
                   from second in original.Start
                   where first != second
                   let pair = new Toy[]
                   {
                     first,
                     second
                   }
                   let flashlight = original.Flashlight - pair.Max(t => t.Time)
                   select Return(new State(
                     original.Start.Except(pair),
                     original.Finish.Concat(pair),
                     flashlight,
                     original.Message + string.Format(
                      "Go {0}. {1} min remaining.\n",
                      string.Join(", ", pair.Select(t => t.Name)),
                      flashlight)))
                   ).Aggregate((oldmax, cur) => cur.Flashlight > oldmax.Flashlight ? cur : oldmax);

      return final;
    }

    static State Return(State original)
    {
      if (!original.Start.Any())
        return original;

      var final = (from toy in original.Finish
                   let flashlight = original.Flashlight - toy.Time
                   let toyColl = new Toy[] { toy }
                   select Go(new State(
                     original.Start.Concat(toyColl),
                     original.Finish.Except(toyColl),
                     flashlight,
                     original.Message + string.Format(
                      "Return {0}. {1} min remaining.\n",
                      toy.Name,
                      flashlight)))
                   ).Aggregate((oldmax, cur) => cur.Flashlight > oldmax.Flashlight ? cur : oldmax);

      return final;
    }
  }

  public class Toy
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Time { get; set; }
    public Toy(string name, int time)
    {
      Name = name;
      Time = time;
    }
  }

  public class State
  {
    public Toy[] Start { get; private set; }
    public Toy[] Finish { get; private set; }
    public int Flashlight { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public State(IEnumerable<Toy> start, IEnumerable<Toy> finish, int flashlight, string message)
    {
      Start = start.ToArray();
      Finish = finish.ToArray();
      Flashlight = flashlight;
      Message = message;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only two solutions are:

```
* Buzz and Woody go right
* Buzz goes left
* Hamm and Rex go right
* Woody goes left
* Woody and Buzz go right
```

and

```
* Buzz and Woody go right
* Woody goes left
* Hamm and Rex go right
* Buzz goes left
* Woody and Buzz go right
```

Use them to check your problem is giving the right results.

Comment: Buzz can't cross the bridge by himself, he needs a flashlight to do so, which is on the opposite side of the bridge.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just realized, I edited the post with the correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

You just made me find out how terribly out of shape I am with AI algorithms :(

I always returned with the fastest guy... bit of a cheat but I'm too tired now to make it work for all combinations. Here's my solution using BFS.

```
class Program
{
    private class Toy
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Time { get; set; }
    }

    private class Node : IEquatable<Node>
    {
        public Node()
        {
            Start = new List<Toy>();
            End = new List<Toy>();
        }

        public Node Clone()
        {
            return new Node
            {
                Start = new List<Toy>(Start),
                End = new List<Toy>(End),
                Time = Time,
                Previous = this
            };
        }

        public int Time { get; set; }
        public List<Toy> Start { get; set; }
        public List<Toy> End { get; set; }
        public Node Previous { get; set; }

        public Toy Go1 { get; set; }
        public Toy Go2 { get; set; }
        public Toy Return { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(Node other)
        {
            return Start.TrueForAll(t => other.Start.Contains(t)) &&
                   End.TrueForAll(t => other.End.Contains(t)) &&
                   Time == other.Time;
        }
    }

    private static void GenerateNodes(Node node, Queue<Node> open, List<Node> closed)
    {
        foreach(var toy1 in node.Start)
        {
            foreach(var toy2 in node.Start.Where(t => t != toy1))
            {
                var newNode = node.Clone();
                newNode.Start.Remove(toy1);
                newNode.Start.Remove(toy2);
                newNode.End.Add(toy1);
                newNode.End.Add(toy2);
                newNode.Go1 = toy1;
                newNode.Go2 = toy2;
                newNode.Time += Math.Max(toy1.Time, toy2.Time);

                if(newNode.Time <= 60 && !closed.Contains(newNode) && !open.Contains(newNode))
                {
                    open.Enqueue(newNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var open = new Queue<Node>();
        var closed = new List<Node>();

        var initial = new Node
                        {
                            Start = new List<Toy>
                                        {
                                            new Toy {Name = "Buzz", Time = 5},
                                            new Toy {Name = "Woody", Time = 10},
                                            new Toy {Name = "Rex", Time = 20},
                                            new Toy {Name = "Ham", Time = 25}
                                        }
                        };

        open.Enqueue(initial);

        var resultNodes = new List<Node>();

        while(open.Count != 0)
        {
            var current = open.Dequeue();
            closed.Add(current);

            if(current.End.Count == 4)
            {
                resultNodes.Add(current);
                continue;
            }

            if(current.End.Count != 0)
            {
                var fastest = current.End.OrderBy(t => t.Time).First();
                current.End.Remove(fastest);
                current.Start.Add(fastest);
                current.Time += fastest.Time;
                current.Return = fastest;
            }

            GenerateNodes(current, open, closed);
        }

        foreach(var result in resultNodes)
        {
            var path = new List<Node>();
            var node = result;
            while(true)
            {
                if(node.Previous == null) break;

                path.Insert(0, node);
                node = node.Previous;
            }

            path.ForEach(n => Console.WriteLine("Went: {0} {1}, Came back: {2}, Time: {3}", n.Go1.Name, n.Go2.Name, n.Return != null ? n.Return.Name : "nobody", n.Time));
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have implementation but here how the solution works:
You always send the fastest pair you got to the other side and return the fastest on the other side, but you never send the same one 2 times(unless everyone was sent 2 times and then you only send fastest that went max 2 times) by marking him(incresing his time by hell).
This can be done with 2 `Priority Queue`s(`O(n log) n` solution time).

The solution for your case:

```
    P-Q 1            P-Q 2
    Buzz
    Woody
    Rex
    Hamm
Buzz + Woody go = 10 min
    P-Q 1            P-Q 2
    Rex              Buzz
    Hamm             Woody
Buzz goes back = 5 min
    P-Q 1            P-Q 2
    Hamm             Woody
    Rex              
    * Buzz
Hamm + Rex go = 25 min
    P-Q 1            P-Q 2
    * Buzz           Woody
                     Hamm
                     Rex
Woody comes back = 10 min
    P-Q 1            P-Q 2
    * Buzz           Hamm
    * Woody          Rex
Woddy + Buzz go = 10 min
---------------------------
Total: 60 mins
```

For example for 6 variation you will do:

```
1 - fastest
2 - after fastest
3 - you got it
4
5
6 - slowest

1 + 2 go
1 goes back
3 + 4 go
2 goes back
5 + 6 go
3 goes back
1 + 2 go
1 goes back
1 + 3 go
```

Comment: Either it's a heuristic and it doesn't work all the time, or it's the correct solution.
Your heuristic won't find the correct solution when you have times (1,5,5,5). If you always send 1 back, you can do that in 17 minutes. Your solution would take 21 minutes.